# Symfony2 - Use Bootstrap (glyphicon) and jQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, symfony-2.6

I am a beginner with Symfony and I am trying to integrate a specific Bootstrap theme and jQuery.

Because of the css files, the js files and the fonts are shared by all the bundles, I put the resources into the `app\Resources\public` directory.

In this directory, I have the following architecture :

- css

  - bootstrap.min.css
  - jquery-ui.min.css
  - my-css.min.css
- fonts

  - glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
  - glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
  - glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
  - glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
- js

  - bootstrap.min.js
  - jquery-1.9.1.min.js

I also have a `layout.html.twig` file in the `app\Resources\views` directory which is my main layout. In this layout, I load the css and the js files with the following twig blocks :

```
<!-- CSS -->
{% block stylesheets %}
  {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    '../app/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '../app/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.min.css'
    '../app/Resources/public/css/my-css.min.css'
  %}
  <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

<!-- JS -->
{% block JavaScript %}
  {% javascripts
    '../app/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'
    '../app/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
  %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

The CSS files are correctly loaded in my pages, but I have an error when I use glyphicon. The icons, on a button for example, are not loaded and in the console of Firefox, I have an error 403 :

```
GET 
http://localhost/mylibrary-web/app/Resources/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 4ms]
```

I try to modify the `security.yml` file without success :

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js|fonts)/
        security: false
```

How can I authorize the access to the `fonts` directory ? Thx for your help !

Comment: You are not supposed to use absolute path like that in assetic. You either provide the short syntax that would be eventually parsed by Symfony: `@AcmeBarBundle/Resources/public/js/form.js` or use the path that starts from your web folder: `'bundles/app/css/*'` Pay attention to your URL, it should not lead to /app/ at all! Take a look at the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: So it means that I should not put my resources into the `app` directory event if they are globals to the app and not specific to a bundle ? I should put the resources into a bundle or directly into the `web` folder ? That's right ?

Comment: If your resources are considered non-bundle specific, then I suppose - yes, you can put them in your `web` folder to be accessed properly. Otherwise, you can use your bundle `Resources` folder and simply use the option `--symlink` for generating assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to work without Assetic...

I put the CSS, JS and font files directly into the `web\bundles\app` directory of the project and use the following code to import the CSS or JS in my Twig layout :

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/custom.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

It is not the best solution but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't configured your web server properly.
If you use Apache server, you can configure it in this way:
https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts